# Using System.Windows.Media.Imaging in MVC results in "The operation completed successfully" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, gdi

We're using WPF libraries to resize images that are uploaded to an MVC action, and we periodically get an error that says "The operation completed successfully".  The error happens on the "new DrawingVisual()" line in the below code.

```
public static BitmapFrame ResizeWithExcess(this BitmapFrame photo, int width, int height)
{
    double dpiX = photo.DpiX == 0 ? 96 : photo.DpiX;
    double dpiY = photo.DpiY == 0 ? 96 : photo.DpiY;

    var targetVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (var targetContext = targetVisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        targetContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, new Rect(0, 0, width * 96 / dpiX, height * 96 / dpiY));
        var x = ((width - (photo.Width * dpiX / 96)) / 2) * 96 / dpiX;
        var y = ((height - (photo.Height * dpiY / 96)) / 2) * 96 / dpiY;
        var w = photo.Width;
        var h = photo.Height;
        targetContext.DrawImage(photo, new Rect(x, y, w, h));
        targetContext.Close();
    }

    var target = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, dpiX, dpiY, PixelFormats.Default);
    target.Render(targetVisual);

    var targetFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(target);
    if (targetVisual.Dispatcher != null) targetVisual.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        return targetFrame;
}
```

The number of handles for the w3wp process, according to task manager, is something around 35k when this happens.  The number of threads is around 270, and "GDI" is 0.  I've tried forcing the dispatcher to initiate shutdown after the BitmapFrame.Create(target), and also added GC code, but none of these seem to make a difference.  Right now the only solution is to recycle the app pool.

I've done some Googling and mostly what I've seen is for WPF apps that are desktop apps, or WPF XAML controls.  Please note that if you'd like to see any of the code that calls this method, I can provide it.  I'm basically using several tasks to have many resized versions created at one time, and I'm using "await" to watch for them to complete.  I've also tried disposing the task, and that didn't seem to do anything at all.

EDIT: We've also seen an error that says "Not enough storage is available to process this command" occur sometimes immediately before the stream of "The operation completed successfully" errors.